# How to check for customer group & country

Tags: checkout, php-5.4

I'm looking to modify a cool little snippet of PHP that I found to use in my cart to show the customer how much more they have to spend to get free shipping. However, I need to add statements to it doesn't show it to customers in a particular customer group and country.

```
<?php if ($this->getQuote()->getSubtotal() < 50): ?>
<?php $subtotalamt = $this->getQuote()->getSubtotal(); ?>
<?php $freeshipamt = 50; ?>
<?php $sumtotal = $freeshipamt - $subtotalamt; ?>
<?php Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($sumtotal); ?>
<p>You are just <span>$<?php print ($sumtotal); ?></span> 
away from earning free shipping!</p>
<?php endif ?>
```

I'm lost as to what I need to add to this to check for the customer group and and country.

Comment: country belongs to shipping country?

Comment: Yes, it would be shipping country. I'm only planning on using this script on my checkout page (not cart).

Comment: In which template you have tried this code?

Comment: I use One Step Checkout from Magestore.com, I have the code placed inside of the shipping_method.phtml file. I tested the code as is, and it works, but I need to disable it for my wholesale customer group and anyone outside of the United States.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code, it works

```
<?php if ($this->getQuote()->getSubtotal()<50): ?>
    <?php $subtotalamt = $this->getQuote()->getSubtotal(); ?>
    <?php $freeshipamt = 50; ?>
    <?php $sumtotal = $freeshipamt - $subtotalamt; ?>
    <?php Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($sumtotal); ?>
    <?php  $loggedIn = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn(); ?>
    <?php if($loggedIn):
                $groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId(); 
                $groupname = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($groupId)->getCustomerGroupCode();
                $shippingCountryId = $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getCountryId();
                if(($groupname != "Wholesale") && ($shippingCountryId == "US")):?>
                        <p>You are just <span>$<?php print ($sumtotal); ?></span> 
                        away from earning free shipping!</p>

                <?php endif ?>  
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Hi saravanavelu, thanks for working this for me, however it's working reverse of what I want. It's showing the text ONLY to wholesale customers in the US. It needs to show only to customers who are not wholesale and/or country is not US.

Comment: as per our conversation you noted as to disable it for wholesale customer group and outside US.

Comment: Hi saravanevelu, I actually tried it again and it did work. However, it only shows to customers who are logged in and who are not wholesale or outside of the US. How can I change it to where if the customer is not logged in, then it would show?

Comment: If not logged in, u can't get the customer group.